# Understanding Scanner.Scan in golang

Tags: go

In scanner, there is a Scan method:

```
// Scan reads the next token or Unicode character from source and returns it.
// It only recognizes tokens t for which the respective Mode bit (1<<-t) is set.
// It returns EOF at the end of the source. It reports scanner errors (read and
// token errors) by calling s.Error, if not nil; otherwise it prints an error
// message to os.Stderr.
func (s *Scanner) Scan() rune {
    ch := s.Peek()

    // reset token text position
    s.tokPos = -1
    s.Line = 0
    ....
```

What does second comment line(It only recognizes tokens t for which the respective Mode bit (1<<-t) is set.) exactly mean?

Comment: Which scanner (package) are you asking about?

Comment: I see it is defined in package scanner.

Comment: It's [`text/scanner`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/scanner#Scanner).

Answer (score 0):

The Scan function allows the code to recognize a certain tokens if the corresponding Mode bitmask is set. This allows the function to be flexible and customizable, as you can specify which types of tokens you want the function to recognize by setting the appropriate bits in the Mode

For example By default golang scanner skips the comments and all literals during the scan, to enable scanning of the comments you might want to do

```
var s scanner.Scanner
s.Mode ^= scanner.SkipComments
```

Comment: So when you say 'a certain token', does it mean we can customize it? So in a lexer program I am trying to understand, I see that for a input string 'span.foo.bar', calling Scanner.TokenText function(after calling Scan function) returns 'span'.